# How to unsubscribe a subscriber within it self

Tags: c#, events, observer-pattern, subscribe, unsubscribe

I have list of events to do. So I add subscriber to list of subscription. after subscriber finishes its job it must unsubscribe itself. it is unknown when subscriber finishes. only subscriber itself knows that.

What would be the best design pattern or solution for it.

I used **Observer pattern**.

**This is my Observable:**

```
internal class EventProvider : IObservable<double>
{
    private readonly List<IObserver<double>> _observers = new List<IObserver<double>>();

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<double> observer)
    {
        // check if observer exist...
        _observers.Add(observer);
        return new Unsubscriber<double>(_observers, observer);
    }

    public void OnTimingsRecieved(double timing) // some other event fires this
    {
        foreach (var observer in _observers)
        {
            observer.OnNext(timing);
        }
    }        

    //...
}
```

**This is the Observer:** (there can be 0 to many observers)

```
internal class EventObserver : IObserver<double>
{
    private IDisposable _unsubscriber;
    private readonly IReadOnlyList<Event> _events;

    public EventObserver(IReadOnlyList<Event> events)
    {
        _events = events;
    }

    public void Subscribe(EventProvider provider)
    {
        _unsubscriber = provider.Subscribe(this);
    }

    private int _ind;
    public void OnNext(double timings)
    {
        // may move to next event or not. it depends.
        // _ind++; may execute or not 

        if (_ind == _events.Count) OnCompleted(); // time to unsubscribe it self
    }

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        _unsubscriber.Dispose();
    } 

    //...
}
```

This is the Unsubscirber which is implemented as usual.

```
internal class Unsubscriber<T> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly List<IObserver<T>> _observers;
    private readonly IObserver<T> _observer;

    internal Unsubscriber(List<IObserver<T>> observers, IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        _observers = observers;
        _observer = observer;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_observers.Contains(_observer))
            _observers.Remove(_observer);
    }
}
```

The problem appears when I try to dispose observer inside `OnNext` event. collection modified because I was inside foreach loop and I disposed i.e removed element from list.

How would you handle a situation where you want to unsubscribe a subscriber within it self? are there any better design patterns?

---

I appreciate to see different approaches rather than using observable and observer.

Assume you have this event.

```
public event EventHandler<double> TimeDiff;
```

And you have many instances of subscribers attached to `TimerDiff` and be able to unsubscribe themselves.

```
public class Reciever
{
    Jobs listOfJobsToDo;

    public void TimeDiffRecieved(double diff)
    { 
       listOfJobsToDo.DoJob(diff);
       if(somecondition)
           Unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you implementing your own observables? That's fraught with danger. You should use the built-in Rx implementation.

Comment: I see. I'm going to remove this observers and try Rx to see how it works thanks for your time.  @Enigmativity

Answer (score 0):

Since foreach cant handle collection changes I used for loop.

In this case we know that when an observer is working it can dispose it self. and others are unaffected.

Here is the correction to provider.

```
public void OnTimingsRecieved(double timing)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _observers.Count; i++)
    {
        var count = _observers.Count;  // save count in case it may change.
        var observer = _observers[i];
        observer.OnNext(timing);        // it may only dispose it self.
        i -= count - _observers.Count; // decrement if observer unsubscribed.
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use this pattern, better reuse ready solutions for that (named Rx (Reactive) extensions).

Comment: looks interesting. that is entirely new thing for me. ill look for that. thanks btw. @Evk